# Calculate mean of each n-rows in a dataframe in r when the first row is varying

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

First make some example data:

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=100))

df1=data.frame(t(c(25,34)))
```

The starting row is different in each column. For example, in X1 I would like to start from 25 th row while in X2 from row 34. Then, I want to calculate the mean for each 5 values for the next 50 rows for all the columns in df.

I am new to R so this is probably very obvious. Can anyone provide some suggestions that how I can do this?

Comment: Please provide the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `Map`.

```
lst <- Map(function(x,y) {x1 <- x[y:length(x)]
                  tapply(x1,as.numeric(gl(length(x1), 5,
                                   length(x1))), FUN=mean)},
                                                     df, df1)
lst
# $X1
#        1           2           3           4           5           6 
#-0.16500158  0.11339623 -0.86961872 -0.54985564  0.19958461  0.35234983 
#       7           8           9          10          11          12 
#0.32792769  0.65989801 -0.30409184 -0.53264725 -0.45792792 -0.59139844 
#     13          14          15          16 
# 0.03934133 -0.38068187  0.10100007  1.21017392 

#$X2
#      1           2           3           4           5           6 
# 0.24525622  0.07367300  0.18733973 -0.43784202 -0.45756095 -0.45740178 
#      7           8           9          10          11          12 
#-0.54086152  0.10439072  0.65660937  0.70623380 -0.51640088  0.46506135 
#     13          14 
#-0.09428336 -0.86295101
```

Because of the length difference, it might be better to keep it as a list.  But, if you need it in a `matrix/data.frame`, you can make the lengths equal by padding with `NAs`.

```
 do.call(cbind,lapply(lst, `length<-`,(max(sapply(lst, length)))))
```

#### Update

If you need only 50 rows, then change `y:(length(x)` to `y:(y+49)` in the `Map` code

#### data

```
  set.seed(24)
  df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(200), nrow=100))
  df1 <- data.frame(t(c(25,34)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear, especially, the second line of your code, but I think this might be close to what you want to do:

```
every_fifth_row <- df[seq(1, nrow(df), 5), ]
every_fifth_row
#             X1          X2
# 1  -0.09490455 -0.28417104
# 6  -0.14949662  0.12857284
# 11  0.15297366 -0.84428186
# 16 -1.03397309  0.04775516
# 21 -1.95735213 -1.03750794
# 26  1.61135194  1.10189370
# 31  0.12447365  1.80792719
# 36 -0.92344017  0.66639710
# 41 -0.88764143  0.10858376
# 46  0.27761464  0.98382526
# 51 -0.14503359 -0.66868956
# 56 -1.70208187  0.05993688
# 61  0.33828525  1.00208639
# 66 -0.41427863  1.07969341
# 71  0.35027994 -1.46920059
# 76  1.38943839  0.01844205
# 81 -0.81560917 -0.32133221
# 86  1.38188423 -0.77755471
# 91  1.53247872 -0.98660308
# 96  0.45721909 -0.22855622

rowMeans(every_fifth_row)
colMeans(every_fifth_row)

# Alternative
# apply(every_fifth_row, 1, mean) # Row-wise mean
# apply(every_fifth_row, 2, mean) # Column-wise mean
```

Comment: Better to use `rowMeans` and `colMeans` here

Comment: Thanks @docendodiscimus always forget about those!